# How to return error 404 on non existent page on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, 404, error

My site got hacked last month and a lot of PDFs were added in Google ending in `/index.php?voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1&static=1866`.

I have cleaned the site but now these pages are redirecting to home page instead of returning error 404. As a result, these pages are still there in Google Search results. Whenever I use `/index.php?voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1&static=1866` this at any WordPress site, it shows homepage only.

But my question is why Google is showing these non existent pages in search results?

One argument can be Gogle previously indexed these pages so it wont remove it from results till they return error 404. How can I make these pages to return error 404?

Comment: You could use canonical links which is always highly recommended which would resolve the issue in time.

Comment: There are thousands and thousands of such pages due to hack.
?voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1&static=1866 is just a example. gpvoq=1&static=1866 is this, number changes and thus, adding the pages

Comment: Use canonical, it'll get rid of those in no time... it tells Google the correct URL, so if you have a page that is accessible via ?string1 ?string2 etc it will tell Google which page is the master, and ignore the rest.

Comment: So to which page should I add canonical? I am sorry I am not that technical guy.

Comment: Presumably these PDFs should not and do not exist on your site? I think perhaps @Simon is assuming that these PDFs exist on the site but should be accessible by a different URL?

Comment: no these pdfs dont exist. Site was hacked before and pdfs were added. I have fixed the site and now these pages dont exist anywhere on the site. 
/index.php?voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1&static=1866, is directing to /?voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1&static=1866 which in returns displayes all pages of my site on single page. 

I checked many wordpress sites by adding /?voxter.pdf&gpvoq=1&static=1866 at the end and they all show the same results. So it seems its normal 

My concern is why google is indexing these non existent pages? How to return error 404 on these results?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress themes support 404 page. You can see the full documentation here 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

It is also useful to display proper http status code 404 while displaying 404 error page.

Answer (score -1):

There are a range of plugins you can add to your WordPress installation which will trigger a 404 error instead of redirecting to the homepage when a page could not be found. I am not going to recommend one as ProWebmasters is not designed for recommending software or plugins but what I will do is give you this link http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=wordpress+hard+404+plugin which will take you the Google search for hard 404 plugins for WordPress.